# How to manage rate-limiting in a distributed system?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, scale

This is what our WebApp for containers service do:

- Take in multiple pdf files
- Send them to Azure OCR service (which is rate-limited at 10 per sec)
- Get the results back, do some processing and send back the response

**Issue:**

Throughout the process, we use multiprocessing to send the files to the OCR service and receive files back (Azure OCR is async in our case). Sometimes when scale hits, we tend to cross the 10 RPS limit.

One thing which can be done is, add a delay. However, our WebApp for container service autoscales on load.

So, the more it autoscales, the higher the delay need to be, as the number of hits increase due to an increase in server instances.

**So, what is a good way to handle this issue?**

Language: Python